# Webpack: Using multiple build targets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, webpack

Given an (Angular-)Webapp with a Webpack-buildprocess I would like to add several build-targets to my Webpack configuration.

There are plenty tutorials on how to modify your webpack.config at compile time, which is already helpful (and probably all I need) to get `dev` and `prod` builds running.

However I was hoping that there is a way to parametrize the build process so that different files are used for the build-process.

**Question**

How do i configure Webpack to replace all `*.js`/ `*.html`-Files with files called `*.mobile.js`/ `*.mobile.html` (if available) during the build-step?

*Bonusquestion:*
How do I exclude environment-specific `import` statements via webpack-config?

**Example**

I got several view/controller-pairs which are linked via Angulars `$stateprovider`. In the mobile version of the webapp most of the `HTML`-views should be a mobile-optimized template.

If I use several entry-points for webpack to generate a desktop-version and a mobile-version I would have to rewrite every file where HTML-Files are required or imported for each of my build-targets and specify the new filenames manually.

This would cause a lot of code-duplication and is hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following in my webpack.config

```
const target = env && env.mobile ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'

resolve: {
    extensions: [`.${target}.js`, '.js', `.${target}.html`, '.html']
}
```